# Shaders.metal only get the y value of the mouse

Tags: macos, metal, compute-shader

I want to use mouse to control camera position computed by `compute function`. in my `view` code:

```
import MetalKit

public class MetalView: MTKView, NSWindowDelegate {

    var queue: MTLCommandQueue! = nil
    var cps: MTLComputePipelineState! = nil

    var timer: Float = 0
    var timerBuffer: MTLBuffer!

    var mouseBuffer: MTLBuffer!
    var pos: NSPoint!

    required public init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.framebufferOnly = false
        device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        registerShaders()
    }


    override public func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        if let drawable = currentDrawable {
            let command_buffer = queue.commandBuffer()
            let command_encoder = command_buffer.computeCommandEncoder()
            command_encoder.setComputePipelineState(cps)
            command_encoder.setTexture(drawable.texture, atIndex: 0)
            command_encoder.setBuffer(timerBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 1)
            command_encoder.setBuffer(mouseBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 2)
            update()
            let threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(8, 8, 1)
            let threadGroups = MTLSizeMake(drawable.texture.width / threadGroupCount.width, drawable.texture.height / threadGroupCount.height, 1)
            command_encoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadGroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupCount)
            command_encoder.endEncoding()
            command_buffer.presentDrawable(drawable)
            command_buffer.commit()
        }
    }

    func registerShaders() {
        queue = device!.newCommandQueue()
        do {
            let library = device!.newDefaultLibrary()!
            let kernel = library.newFunctionWithName("compute")!
            timerBuffer = device!.newBufferWithLength(sizeof(Float), options: [])
            mouseBuffer = device!.newBufferWithLength(sizeof(NSPoint), options: [])
            cps = try device!.newComputePipelineStateWithFunction(kernel)
        } catch let e {
            Swift.print("\(e)")
        }
    }

    func update() {
        timer += 0.01
        var bufferPointer = timerBuffer.contents()
        memcpy(bufferPointer, &timer, sizeof(Float))
        bufferPointer = mouseBuffer.contents()
        memcpy(bufferPointer, &pos, sizeof(NSPoint))
    }

    override public func mouseDragged(event: NSEvent) {
        pos = convertPointToLayer(convertPoint(event.locationInWindow, fromView: nil))
        let scale = layer!.contentsScale
        pos.x *= scale
        pos.y *= scale
        debugPrint("Hello",pos.x,pos.y)
    }
}
```

and my shader code:

```
kernel void compute(texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]],
                    constant float &timer [[buffer(1)]],
                    constant float2 &mouse [[buffer(2)]],
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    int width = output.get_width();
    int height = output.get_height();
    float2 uv = float2(gid) / float2(width, height);
    uv = uv * 2.0 - 1.0;
    // scale proportionately.
    if(width > height) uv.x *= float(width)/float(height);
    if(width < height) uv.y *= float(height)/float(width);


    float2 mpos = mouse * 2.0 - 1.0;

    float3 cameraPosition = float3( mpos.x,mpos.y, -10.0 );///<-- mouse position to set camera position

...

}
```

But somehow I only get the `mpos.y` value. It seems like `mpos.x` is not send over to the `compute` function. How can I resolve this?

Comment: can you provide more evidence that you don't have a value for mpos.x in the shader?

Comment: I play around `float3 cameraPosition = float3( mpos.x,mpos.y, -10.0 );`, say `float3( mpos.x,0.0, -10.0 )` and `float3( 0.0,mpos.x, -10.0 )` just to see if `mpos.x` is working, which as I aspect, it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSPoint`'s fields are `CGFloat`. I think the issue is that, for 64-bit, `CGFloat` is defined as `Double`, not `Float`. Metal's `float` corresponds to Swift's `Float`, not `Double`. Presumably, `float2` corresponds to two Swift `Float`s. Your buffer layout is wrong. Copy two `Float`s, not an `NSPoint`, into `mouseBuffer`.

Comment: I am not sure how to convert `nspoint` to `float2`. So instead, I use 2 `float`s and put into 2 `mouse buffer`(x and y). Then it works.